# Android Studio "Scanning For Files To Index"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to achieve the following project structure in Android Studio

```
project/
    projectA/
    projectB/
```

Where `projectA` is an "app" module created by Android Studio which I have renamed, and `projectB` is a Kotlin project I wish to depend on in the app. I can get the projects to appear correctly as modules in my project however no matter what I try, as soon as I add `projectB` to my Android Studio project, it seems to get stuck in a loop "searching for files to index". When I look at the files it is always just looping through the same 2-3 files. They are always META-INF files but not always the same ones.

How do I successfully add a module to an Android Studio Project without hitting this error or how can I set out my project from the start to achieve this structure?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "add to Android Studio"? How are you doing that? You could just manually edit the settings.gradle file to include projectB

Comment: So I've tried adding it via the settings.gradle and also via the  File>New>Import Module dialog. Both seem to have the same effect.

Comment: Hmm. I assume the other project has a lot of dependencies?

Comment: `projectB` depends on Spring Boot (and thus Jackson) but that's it. Like I say, it seems to get stuck looping through a few files. By which I mean if I watch the file name under the progress bar it just cycles. Though each time I invalidate the cache it seems to cycle through a different few.

Comment: Might be worth upgrading the Gradle plugin / wrapper

Comment: How does one do that? I'm currently using the "default gradle wrapper". Gradle seems to be version 4.4 and I'm using Android Studio 3.1.

Comment: I think that's the latest, but you can check https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I had a `gradle/` directory under  my `project/projectB` directory that was there because the project was originally created as a standalone project by IntelliJ. Deleting that fixed the issue.