# Kotlin + Gradle Unresolved Reference

Tags: android-studio, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721542/android-studio-scanning-for-files-to-index) I'm trying to setup the following project structure

```
project/
   settings.gradle
   projectB/  # some common code (using spring-boot)
       build.gradle
       com/
          foo/
             bar/...
   projectA/  # an android app
       build.gradle
       com/
          foo/
             baz/...
```

`settings.gradle` looks like

```
rootProject.name = "project"
include ":projectB"
project(":projectB").projectDir = new File(rootDir, './projectB')
include ":projectA"
project(":projectA").projectDir = new File(rootDir, './projectA')
```

and in `projectA/build.gradle` I have

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":projectB")
}
```

Android Stuido seems happy and will provide code completion and searching for code in `projectB` within `projectA`. However compilation fails with an error

```
Unsresolved reference: bar
```

on the line where I try to `import com.foo.bar.whatever`.

I have tried a number of different changes to the various gradle files but nothing has fixed this error.

What is the problem with this setup and how can it be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: In `settings.gradle` just use `include ":projectA", ":projectB" ` and check. I have a multi module project configured in same way, I don't face any issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that's one of the variations I tried already

Comment: :( Try Invalidating cache and restart Android studio.

Comment: Alas, I've also tried that several times. It builds neither in Android Studio, nor by calling `./gradelw clean build` from the command line.

Comment: `Open Module Settings` check if your modules and their dependencies are listed properly, check If a module has any cyclic dependencies and remove if any exists.

Comment: I can't see anything untoward there. However, the available tabs are different for the two modules, as are the icons. `projectA` has a green circle next to its folder and several tabs, whereas `projectB` has a blue square/cup (in the tree view & settings respectively) and only the dependencies tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170947/discussion-between-blizzard-and-dan).

Comment: Have you tried using `api` instead of `implementation`?

Comment: Your folder structure is not really `com/something/something`, right? It should be `src/main/java/com/something/something` unless you specifically altered the source directories

Comment: I believe I'm seeing the same issue. Android module `app` depends on android module `core` and things are fine in Java-land. However when a Kotlin unit test in `app` imports a Kotlin class from `core` I get the same misbehavior as Dan. AS looks happy but `Unresolved Reference` when building (ide or command line).

Comment: @Nexcius Sorry, the directory structure is as it should be, I just transcribed it incorrectly.

Comment: @PFuster I tried that already. Unfortunately it doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

in Android Studio & IntelliJ IDE, it is better to define these as "modules".

eg. with a `settings.gradle` alike:

```
include ":projectA", ":projectB"
rootProject.name = "project"
```

with a directory structure alike:

```
project/
   settings.gradle
   projectB/  # common code
       build.gradle
       src/
          test/
          debug/
          main/
             res/
             assets/
             java/
             kotlin/
                com/
                   foo/
                      bar/...


   projectA/  # android app
       build.gradle
       src/
          test/
          debug/
          main/
             res/
             assets/
             java/
             kotlin/
                com/
                   foo/
                      baz/...
```

when intending to use other directory-structure, one has the change the `sourceSets` configuration.